# Oracle SQL Create Date from Parts

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two date fields in a database called "EFFECTIVE_DATE" and "POINT_DATE"

How do I create a new date field, where the date is made up from the year of "EFFECTIVE_DATE", the month of "POINT_DATE"  and the day of "POINT_DATE" ?

I would normally use Datefromparts, but this is an Oracle Database not Microsoft

Kind Regards

Comment: There may be a more elegant way but `TO_CHAR()` and `TO_DATE()` should work. You can also use `EXTRACT()`. The hard part is ensuring you don't end up with invalid dates, e.g. `Feb 31`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach using `ADD_MONTHS` and `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ....)`. You simply add or subtract the needed number of months (always a multiple of 12, since you are only changing the year). Unlike the `TO_CHAR` / `TO_DATE` solutions, this approach handles leap days (Feb. 29). On the other hand, be advised that changing the date from 28 Feb. 2003 to the year 2012 will change it to Feb. 29 (`ADD_MONTHS` changes the last day of a month to the last day of the resulting month).

```
with
     inputs as (
       select date '2013-03-22' as effective_date,
              date '2017-08-14' as point_date
       from   dual
     )
-- end of TEST data (do not include in the solution!)
select effective_date, point_date,
       add_months(point_date, 12 * ( extract (year from effective_date) - 
                                     extract (year from point_date)     )
                 ) as mixed_date
from   inputs;

EFFECTIVE_DATE  POINT_DATE  MIXED_DATE
--------------  ----------  ----------
03/22/2013      08/14/2017  08/14/2013
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . this produces a nice string in the YYYY-MM-DD format:

```
select to_char(effective_date, 'YYYY') || '-' || to_char(point_date, 'MM-DD')
```

And this parses it back to a date:

```
select to_date(to_char(effective_date, 'YYYY') || '-' || to_char(point_date, 'MM-DD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Note:  You might want to be careful about Feb 29th.

Comment: And be careful of dates like June 31st.

Comment: @unleashed . . . I don't see how this would product June 31st.  I do see how it would produce 2017-02-29.

Comment: My bad.  At the time, I was thinking it was taking just the day from the second date.  If it takes a valid day AND month, then this is fine except for 2/29 scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all coulmns are `DATE` data types, you can use this one

```
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(EFFECTIVE_DATE, 'YYYY') || TO_CHAR(POINT_DATE, 'MMDD'), 'YYYYMMDD')
```

Be aware of leap years!