# Simple statement to update only the month and year from oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, date, sql-update

I am using Oracle SQL and I have dates made from different months and year. However, I need a simple update statement to update to a specific month and year without changing the day.

I tried to use add_months along with months_between but it throws some error saying inconsistent datatypes. So this will not work.

Commands i tried:

```
UPDATE MYDATE=ADD_MONTHS(MYDATE,MONTHS_BETWEEN(TRUNC('Jun','mm'),trunc(MYDATE,'mm)))
```

For example:

```
MYDATE
01/02/18
03/05/17
```

Expected result:

```
01/06/19
03/06/19
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle SQL Create Date from Parts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42769518/oracle-sql-create-date-from-parts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
update tab
   set mydate=to_date(to_char(mydate,'dd')||'06'||to_char(sysdate,'yyyy'),'ddmmyyyy')
```

since `month` is fixed and `year` is current

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=21933bf32f411321e7b2fbf6580aafdd)</kbd>

Alternatively, you can try

```
update tab
   set mydate=add_months( mydate, round(months_between(
                         to_date('2019-06-'||to_char(mydate,'dd'),'yyyy-mm-dd'),mydate)) )
```

with `add_months` and `months_between` together

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1d9f300f4cd6dc6d2509f78c05630e35)</kbd>

Comment: Hi I tried executing this but it has been running for very long. Is there any other statement?

Comment: @user9340817 Hi I added the other case.